# UIButton titleLabel not displaying center aligned.

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a button in my ios project which displays edit profile if the user is the current user and follow if the user is not the current user.

I am setting the titleLabel text programmatically dependant on the above condition. I am also programatically setting the button text to align center.

The problem I'm having is it works perfectly for the edit profile button which appears as it should center aligned but when showing the follow button the word follow is slightly off center to the left and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Here is my code:

```
 if([userID isEqualToString:credentialID]){
        self.followEditBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
        self.followEditBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xA6B9C1).CGColor;
        self.followEditBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        self.followEditBtn.layer.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xF8FBFC).CGColor;
        self.followEditBtn.titleLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xA1B1C3);
        self.followEditBtn.titleLabel.text = @"Edit Profile";
        self.followEditBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    } else {
        self.followEditBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
        self.followEditBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x19A548).CGColor;
        self.followEditBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        self.followEditBtn.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        self.followEditBtn.titleLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x19A548);
        self.followEditBtn.titleLabel.text = @"Follow";
        self.followEditBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    }
```

And some images of the buttons as you can see the follow text is slightly off center to the left yet the edit profile button is correctly aligned:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know it is a bit of a hack, but have you tried self.followEditBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0); ?  You would only have to do it for the follow part of the if else.  You would have to play around with the values to get it just right.

Comment: Though it seems okay from your code that you posted, are you sure you typed @"Follow" correctly? Sometimes we tend to no notice that we put extra spaces after the text.

Comment: Hi guys totally forgot about this. I had typed the right amount of spaces @jeraldo and thanks for the suggestion Douglas although I want to avoid the hack around. The answer from Gian solved my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your problem (iOS 6.1 to 7.1). Although I had to make a small change in order to make it work, since it wasn't showing any text.
Instead of using:

```
self.followEditBtn.titleLabel.text = @"Edit Profile";
```

you should use:

```
[self.followEditBtn setTitle:@"Follow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I'm assuming you're using a UIButtonTypeCustom type UIButton, and having a fixed frame size.

I'd like you to tell me where are you putting this code, and how is this button being initialized.

Comment: Thanks Gian this fixed my problem after setting it the `forState` way.  I've accepted the answer and upvoted.